# Parseval Identity, Hilbert-Schmidt Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

In Werner I am reding the following equation on page 322 a proof about a property of Hilbert Schmidt operators that states the following equality ($(g_{n})$ is orthonormal basis):

$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\Big\lVert\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}s_{n}\langle g_{m},e_{n}\rangle f_{n}\Big\rVert^{2} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}s_{n}^{2}|\langle g_{m},e_{n}\rangle|^{2}
$$

Looks to me like Parseval identity should be used here, but I dont see how exactly. Any clue?

Comment: sorry, jus edited

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what exactly everything is. I suspect that the $s_n$ are scalars, and that the $e_n,f_n,g_n$ are vectors. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the $s_n$ are non-negative scalars (possibly singular values) and that the $f_n$ form an orthonormal basis. If so, then the result follows from the general fact that for (complex) scalars $(a_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$, we have
$$
\left\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty  a_n f_n\right\|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2.
$$

Comment: Does this have any name so I can find a proof of it?

Comment: @craft This is sometimes referred to as [Parseval's identity/relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) (though it isn't necessarily a statement about Fourier coefficients).

Comment: Isnt that actually the pythagorean theorem? Because Im getting the norm into the sum. Then I can take out $s_{n}^2$ of the norm since it is a scalar hmm...

Comment: @craft Well the "Pythagorean theorem" is typically used to refer only to the 2-dimensional or finite-dimensional version, but essentially yes. In infinite dimensions, we just have to be a bit careful since we have infinite series to deal with.